# Can 2 unique Instruments have the same ISIN?

Tags: equities, bond, market-data

I always thought that 1 ISIN uniquely identifies 1 financial instrument. However, I have come across cases, where the **same ISIN** is used for a **stock** and a **bond**:

1. `NZFCND0004S9` is ISIN for perpetual **bond** `NUFAU Float PERP Corp` and **stock** `NFNG AU Equity`.
2. `AU0000SBKHB3` is ISIN for perpetual **bond** `SUNAU Float PERP Corp` and **stock** `SBKHB AU Equity`.

Is my reference data incorrect?

Looking at the price history of bond `NUFAU Float PERP Corp` and stock `NFNG AU Equity`, we see they are essentially the same from 2020 to 2022 (so having the same ISIN *could* make sense). However, in 2019 they were significantly different.

[image]

---

Does anybody know how it can happen that 2 distinct instruments have the same ISIN?

Comment: Very unusual. Perhaps you could ask Nufarm Finance NZ Ltd. investor relations if something happened in mid-October 2019 to "make" the two securities the same.

Comment: I don't know what the rules are behind ISIN assignments but in 1) It looks like the company is an Special Purpose Vehicle set up to issue notes for Nufarm. 2) Equity is suspended but might also be similar to 1).

Comment: Here's another example of distinct instruments with the same ISIN: [EQQQ](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/EQQQ/invesco/company-page) and [EQQU](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/EQQU/invesco/company-page). These are 2 (related) ETFs listed on the London Stock Exchange.